# Как симулировать клик мышкой в Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

Я использую [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) в своем проекте. Когда я кликаю мышкой на какое-то время дня в календаре срабатывает обработчик ивента, как например в этом примере

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainCalendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    selectable: true,
    select: onCalendarSelect,
  });
});

function onCalendarSelect(start, end) {
  alert('hello from select event!');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.js"></script>



<div id = "mainCalendar">< /div>
```

Но могу понять как симулировать на клик на слот с временем с помощью Selenium IDE ? Куда кликать?

Comment: Я не знаю тематику вопроса, т.к. учу Java. Но нагуглил вот это - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348937/click-in-ok-button-inside-an-alert-selenium-ide

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, как определить элемент, по которому необходимо кликнуть?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, да. Я нашел кучу команд, click, mouseDown, FireEvent и кликнуть по кнопке у меня проблем нет, но тут не могу разобраться что кликать

Comment: ну вам надо определить элемент, по которому вы хотите кликнуть. в данном случае, что кликнуть по строке 6am, необходимо идентифицировать элемент както так ( по xpath) .//tr[@data-time='06:00:00']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, проблема была не в том что я не тот элемент кликал, а в том как делался клик. Ивент `select` был навешан на последовательность из двух ивентов `MouseDown` и потом `MouseUp`.

Поэтому чтобы кликнуть по времени на fullcalendar нужно использовать следующий код :

```
selenium.MouseDownAt("xpath=(//tr[@data-time='10:00:00']/td[2])", "2,2");
selenium.MouseUp("xpath=(//tr[@data-time='10:00:00'])");
```